# Spring Boot 3 Actuator Indentation not working

Tags: java, spring-boot

Created a new Spring Initializer project in IntelliJ using Spring Boot version 3.0.2.
Included Spring Web and Spring Boot Actuator.

Did the same using Spring Boot version 2.7.8.

Both projects have the following in application.properties

`management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=info` 
`management.info.build.enabled=true`
`spring.jackson.serialization.indent-output=true`

When requesting /actuator/info for version 3.0.2 project, the JSON is not indented or pretty printed.
The same request for version 2.7.8 project returns pretty printed and indented JSON.

Everything is left default, no code additions, config changes. etc. Just plain vanilla out of the box project.

Is this a bug in Spring Boot version 3?

Expected the JSON response to be pretty printed and indented as per the Spring documentation for the Application Properties settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This change has been introduced in Spring Boot 3 on purpose: changing a JSON configuration in your main application should not change the JSON format used by actuator, as it could confuse clients relying on the format to be the same for all Spring Boot applications.

See [the related issuue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/20291)  and also [the dedicated section in the migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide#actuator-json). You can revert to the previous behavior by setting the `management.endpoints.jackson.isolated-object-mapper=false` configuration property.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction @Brian-clozal.
Out of interest, if we wanted to configure the isolated Actuator ObjectMapper, how would we go about doing that?

Comment: You can create a custom `org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jackson.EndpointObjectMapper` bean that provides the `ObjectMapper` instance configured for your convenience.